# Results showing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I've been using geocoding API V3 for such a good time and yesterday I've been noticed that not all results are been displayed correctly. I mean, some streets just do not appear. Users said that some streets used to appear, but they are not appearing anymore.

The system is working basically in Londrina - Parana - Brazil and some streets in question are 'Rua Sen. Souza Naves - Londrina, Parana - Brazil' and 'Rua Pará - Londrina, Parana - Brazil'

I can find these streets through google maps normally..

I'd really appreciate some help.

Regards,

Marlon Pascoal

Comment: Works  for me: [**Rua Pará - Londrina, Parana - Brazil**](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3DRua%20Par%E1%20-%20Londrina%2C%20Parana%20-%20Brazil)  and [**Rua Sen. Souza Naves - Londrina, Parana - Brazil**](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3DRua%20Sen.%20Souza%20Naves%20-%20Londrina%2C%20Parana%20-%20Brazil) . We can't help you without seeing any code.

Comment: You're right, it's working normally again. Might it be some maintenance performed by google?